# AWS Lambda triggered by PUT to s3 bucket in separate account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am trying to trigger a Lambda function to run on update to a s3 bucket. The s3 bucket that I am attempting to have trigger the Lambda is in a separate AWS account.

The approach I have tried is setting up a role in the account that with the s3 bucket that has all the privileges on the s3 bucket. Then in the account with the Lambda I have a role with assumes the role in the other account like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::..."
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I am not able to see the s3 bucket in the list of buckets to trigger the Lambda event.

Is using a s3 bucket in a separate account to trigger a Lambda possible? Is this the correct solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE:** It appears that cross-account triggering of a Lambda function from S3 actually *is* possible. See: [Using Resource-Based Policies for AWS Lambda (Lambda Function Policies)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html)

---

**Old answer:**

**Amazon S3** can trigger an **AWS Lambda** function when objects are added to, or deleted from, a bucket.

However, this trigger must be setup **on the bucket itself**. You will need the owner of the bucket (or someone with sufficient permissions) to set the configuration to trigger Lambda.

Also, the Lambda function being called must be in the **same Account as the Amazon S3 bucket**. You could create a Lambda function in one account that then calls a Lambda function in another account (given sufficient permissions), but it is **not possible** for a Bucket in Account A to directly trigger a Lambda function in Account B.

Answer (score 3):

Lets assume that your bucket is in Account-A, and your lambda in Account-B. You can actually do that in the following way:

1. add permission to the lambda function to be invoked from the
   Account-A S3 bucket events:

   ```
   aws lambda add-permission \
     --function-name MyFunction \
     --region <your-region> \
     --statement-id <whatever> \
     --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" \
     --principal s3.amazonaws.com \
     --source-arn <source-bucket-arn> \
     --source-account <Account-A-id> \
   ```
2. in the event triggering of S3, specify the ARN of your lambda function

Comment: sorry for bad formatting, i still need to improve on that point :p

Comment: Thanks!  it worked great. For those who are wondering where can you get the Account-A-Id, it's the numeric id in your account settings

Comment: happy to help :) you can also find your account ID in the ARN of the resources or in the "support" panel if needed

Comment: @Tom I'm able to trigger my Lambda in account A from account B when an object is added to account B. I get the bucket name and object key name in my lambda function in account A. However I'm attempting to copy the the object from B into A but I'm running into an access denied error. Any thoughts on permissions I might need?  ```await s3.copyObject({ Bucket: `my-destination-bucket`, CopySource: `/${sourceBucket}/mel${key}`, Key: key, ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control' });```

Comment: @MelvinGaye my answer only shows how to add permissions to trigger the lambda cross account. In your case, it looks like you need to also configure cross-account access to be able to copy the objects from the bucket in account B using the IAM role of the lambda function in account A. Check this out https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3 , I think it should do the trick

Comment: @Tom thank you this is similar to what I found. Ended up creating a resource policy.